# Remote mail() function

Tags: php

I am trying to use my localhost to connect to another server remotely and execute a mail function so i use get method to send the email and the subject
here is my localhost file :

```html
<?php
for ($email=0; $email< $n_emails; $email++){
$urlsmtp = $link.'?email='.$destino.'&subject='.$tornado.'&msg='.$msgrand.'&name='.$_POST['naming'].'&from='.$_POST['localting'];
//this link is something like http://test.com/RemoteSmpt.php?email=test@mail.com &subject=test&msg=test&name=test&from=test
$urlsmtp = str_replace(" ", "%20", $urlsmtp);
$response = file_get_contents($urlsmtp);
}
?>
```

and the file RemoteSmpt.php which i will put it in the server contains this code :

```html
<?php
if ( isset( $_GET['email']) && $_GET['subject'] && $_GET['msg'] && $_GET['name'] && $_GET['from']) {
  $email = $_GET['email'];
  $subject = $_GET['subject'];
  $msg = $_GET['msg'];
  $name = $_GET['name'];
  $from = $_GET['from'];
  $headers    = 'From: '.$name.'<'.$from.'>\n';
  $enviar = mail($email, $subject, $msg, $headers);
if ($enviar){
echo ('<font color="green"> -'. $email .' 0k -- With Subject : '.$subject.'</font><br>');
} else {
echo ('<font color="red"> -'. $email .' Not Sended -- With Subject : '.$subject.'</font><br>');
}
}else
{echo 'Invalid Data !<br>';}
?>
```

so after i upload the RemoteSmpt.php file and try this is what i got : 
Warning: file_get_contents(http://...@mail.com&subject=tset&msg=test&name=test&from=test): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in Mylocalhost file !
Please any idea how to fix this code !

Comment: does `file_get_contents($link)` also return a 404?

Comment: return Warning: file_get_contents(http://...@mail.com&subject=tset&msg=test&name=test&from=test): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in (the file_get_contents line)

Comment: $link is the url without the argument string

Comment: i fixed the links i got an espace in some of them but the problem now is that when the function file_get_contents calls the url for the mail function only the last one works ...

Comment: Nothing in the loop uses the `$email` variable. You're sending the same email every iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly encode special characters in the URL parameters, which can be done using `urlencode()`.

You can use the `http_build_query()` function to build a query string from an associative array, and properly encode everything.

```
$params = http_build_query([
    'email' => $destino,
    'subject' => $tornado,
    'msg' => $msgrand,
    'name' => $_POST['naming'],
    'from' => $_POST['localting']
]);
$urlsmtp = $link . '?' . $params;
```